# Run a Common Lisp file from the CLISP interface (Error)

Tags: compiler-errors, common-lisp, clisp

Everywhere I looked, it says, you can run a CLISP file with the command

"$ clisp file.lisp" from the CLISP terminal. I tried it with a simple (print "Hello World!"), saved it as lisp1.lisp. It doesn't work if I type in "$ clisp lisp1.lisp" and I get the error message:
[image]

I tried to find my mistake and looked everywhere on the internet, but others type it in and it just works. I already the path variable to the clisp directory. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where did you look? Where did you find that information? What is a 'CLISP terminal'? What is '$'? You know that function calls in Lisp begin with a parenthesis?

Comment: @RainerJoswig: For example here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/lisp-hello-world-example-how-to-write-and-execute-lisp-program-on-linux-os/   under point 3.) there is this method to run a lisp file. By "CLISP terminal" I'm referring to the CLISP interpreter.

Comment: The example runs a file from the Unix shell. You are trying something different. Are you sure you don't know that '$' is a shell prompt? ;-)

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I did not know that. But what would be the equivalent windows command to run it directly from the CLISP interpreter?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. The example runs CLISP from a shell. You paste that line into Lisp. Why would you want to run 'windows commands' from Lisp? If you want to run Windows commands, use the windows shell.
If you want to use Lisp, here CLISP, you should learn and use Lisp. See a typical Lisp book for the basics:  https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/  You can download a beginner's Lisp book from there.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: Normally I would just type in the variables and functions etc. in the interpreter, then execute it without saving it to a file. But now I want to create a source code file with notepad++, save it to a file lisp1.lisp, then go to the lisp interpreter (CLISP) and execute the .lisp file from the desktop. What would be the command to type into CLISP interpreter to do such thing?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the CLISP shell in windows.

Comment: Why not? Have you checked a Lisp book or manual how to load code from Lisp?

Comment: There is no CLISP shell. CLISP is a Lisp interpreter/compiler. Not a shell. You can't execute windows shell commands in CLISP, especially not if you paste a shell prompt into a Lisp interpreter/compiler REPL.

Comment: I'm currently watching Derek Banas' LISP tutorial on youtube. He executed the lisp file like that, but I can't.

Comment: So can I execute the file from standard cmd?

Comment: He can't, because it does not work. You can execute Windows commands in Lisp. Lisp is a programming language with s-expression syntax, not a windows shell.

Comment: Look: "$ clisp lisp1.lisp". $ is a prompt and useless. 'clisp lisp1.lisp' is a shell command. Execute it from the shell, not from Lisp.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymSq4wHrqyU mark 5:27. I want to do the exact same thing.

Comment: If, by shell, you mean cmd, i've tried that but I get "$" is not recognized as an external or internal command...

Comment: The example is on a Mac, not windows. The clisp command is typed to a shell. $ is its prompt. Read what I write. $ is a prompt. The command is        clisp foo.lisp   .  CLISP is a program, You need to execute it and you can give it parameters. Don't type '$'. A program or command named '$' does not exist.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: Thanks, without the $ it worked.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: But now it closes so fast after execution. Is there a way to keep the window open without waiting for user input? Like in the video but for windows?

Comment: Don't know, I'm not using Windows and the video uses a Mac, too.

Comment: Execute cmd, then in it you execute your line. The window won't close.

Comment: Entering "clisp lisp1.lisp" into cmd.exe will likely not work. Unlike on Unix, Windows programs don't typically install within the `PATH`. Instead, they end up in their own directory under `C:\Program Files` and you have to type the entire path to invoke the executable (or add the relevant folder to the `PATH`, or move the executable and its DLLs, or cd/chdir to the correct directory before typing the command (and the Lisp source file must be in the same directory)).

Comment: @de_dust Here, you can see how to `load` your file from the REPL. [load](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_load.html)

Comment: Judging from your picture, it looks like you are already in the CLISP interpreter - the REPL (see the `[1]>` prompt?) and then trying to run `$ clisp` from inside the REPL. That doesn't work. You aren't doing exactly what your training video is saying . Exit the interpreter first (press Ctrl-D until you get a shell prompt), then try your `clisp lisp1.lisp` (do not put a `$` in front of it yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you saw, they ran the command from a terminal, and the `$` is just an indication that it is running a shell command as a user, this is a common practice when writing shell commands for UNIX-like environments (such as Linux or Mac).

So to execute a lisp file *from the command line/terminal* you would open the terminal (cmd.exe on windows) and type `clisp lisp1.lisp`.

Alternatively, if you want to load a file inside the clisp interpreter you would type `(load "lisp1.lisp")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running CLISP on windows you have to config your shorcut.

- Right click on your shorcut
- Propierties
- Start in: "the direcory on you saved your lisp1.lisp"

After that you have to open CLISP from the shortcut and then you have two options to load your file:

- (load 'lisp1.lisp)
- (load "lisp1.lisp")

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Windows. following your installation of clisp you must set your system variable path to contain the location of clisp.exe, and the location of the lisp program. for example, if you installed clisp on c:\clisp-2.49 and you wrote a lisp program hello.lisp with Notepad stored on your desktop, then your system variable path must contain this:
...;c:\clisp-2.49;c:\users(yourUserName)\desktop;...
Note: using clisp through command line prompt works only if your lisp program does not require interaction. Lisp since 1958 has been designed for REPL (Read-Evaluate-Print Loop), you must grasp this Lisp philosophy as it is the foundational idea of John McCarthy's Lisp.

Comment: one more thing: Lisp in all flavors uses buffers to handle all inputs and outputs. the fact that you can save Lisp functions as files is useless unless they're loaded into the Lisp buffers as you call those functions.